# Parameterized query with string literal in node-postgres

Tags: node-postgres

I'm trying to write a node-postgres query that takes an integer to use in an interval as a parameter:

```
  const query = {
    text:
      `SELECT
        foo 
        FROM bar 
        WHERE 
          DATE(created_at) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL '$1 DAYS';`,
    values: [daysAgo]
  }
```

When I run this, it gives this error message indicating it's not seeing the `$1` because it's enclosed in single quotes:

> bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0

Is there a supported way to do this? If not, what is the best work around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [this reference](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/2B704E31-B533-4159-B6F0-EC284CFE824C%40skype.net) which shows you can use the convention of `'1 DAY' * X`.

I was able to get this working thus:

```
   (async () => {
       const { rows } = await pgpool.query(`
          SELECT id, name FROM users 
           WHERE DATE(created) <= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL '1 DAY' * $1;`,
           [req.params.daysAgo]);
```

Comment: @alexroussos, if you need to see the full call with catch(), etc. Let me know and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks